How to use gRPC client event listener as a source for Apache Flink
I am trying to implement a gRPC client as a source for my Apache Flink application. The goal is to read streaming data from a gRPC event listener (the gRPC client is salesforce PubSub Api for Change data capture) and process it in Flink. The idea is to schedule multiple grpc client to flink as a source and want to manage this dynamically like remove or adding a new client when required
What is the best way to integrate a gRPC client with Flink as a source? Are there any best practices or patterns I should follow?
So far I tried to create a custom source as
class GrpcSource(Source):
    def __init__(self, argument_dict):
        self.argument_dict = argument_dict
        self.running = True

    def run(self, ctx):
        cdc_listener = PubSub(self.argument_dict)
        cdc_listener.auth()
        cdc_listener.subscribe(
            self.argument_dict["topic"], "LATEST", "", 1, self.process_event, ctx
        )

    def process_event(self, event, pubsub, ctx):
        if event.events:
            for evt in event.events:
                payload_bytes = evt.event.payload
                schema_id = evt.event.schema_id
                decoded_event = pubsub.decode(
                    pubsub.get_schema_json(schema_id), payload_bytes
                )
                # Emit the decoded event to the Flink context
                ctx.collect(decoded_event)

    def cancel(self):
        self.running = False

def main(argument_dict):
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_parallelism(1)

    # Define the gRPC source
    grpc_source = GrpcSource(argument_dict)
    ds = env.from_source(
        grpc_source, WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps(), "GrpcSource"
    )

    # Process the stream (example: print the events)
    ds.print()

    # Execute the Flink job
    env.execute("gRPC Flink Job")


but getting the error as self._j_function AttributeError: 'GrpcSource' object has no attribute '_j_function'

An easier alternative to making a source is leveraging Flink's AsyncIO support. Is there a particular reason why you need a source? More details on how you plan to use the Salesforce data would help with understanding the best approach.

Salesforce provides it's object changes (due to any crud op) as gRPC response and I want to persist this data as kafka topic, which later on consumed by my upstream system, I want flink to stream these event response, basically to work as an task manager which should handle creating a new gRPC listener or shutdown an running client on demand. Here source of data comes from salesforce grpc response, so thought of having it as the source for flink
